# IonicFramework: Pull to Refresh not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the Ionic's [Pull to Refresh tool](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/) for first time but still not working for me

this is a controller where I am calling a factory/service in order to have a list of sports in the view

```
.controller('sportsCtrl', function($scope, SportsFactory, AuthFactory) {

 $scope.sports = [];

    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        if (sports.length) {
          $scope.sports = sports;
        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }
     //Here is the function to call the refresher//
        $scope.doRefresh = function() {
          $scope.sports = sports;
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
          $scope.$apply();
        };
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-refresher
  pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
  on-refresh="doRefresh()">
</ion-refresher>
```

does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You're setting `doRefresh` in the `getSportsWithLeagues` resolve.  That is, you're always setting it to the value `sports` that was returned the first time that resolved, you're **not** calling `getSportsWithLeagues` on each `doRefresh`

Comment: sorry I barely got you. Can you help me with a little piece of code ?

Comment: Try reading this first and it'll make more sense. http://ionicframework.com/blog/pull-to-refresh-directive/

Comment: I *imagine* you want `doRefresh()` to call `SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues()`.  Move that function *outside* of the resolve that its in, i.e., directly below `$scope.sports = []`. Then, inside of `doRefresh`, do `SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) { $scope.sports = sports; })`

Comment: looking at this again, the code is all out of order.  I was trying to fix it in an answer but you have multiple services nested inside each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `doRefresh()` is defined in the wrong location.  It is defined inside the resolve function for `getSportsWithLeagues`.  It should be defined as a property on the controller.  The code is all out of order, This should be a better order of operations:

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
        $scope.customer = customer;
        SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
            if (sports.length) {
                $scope.sports = sports;
            }else {
                AuthFactory.logout();
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    };
};
```

Comment: He will need to call `getSportsWithLeagues` inside of `doRefresh` still -- the way you have it, `sports` will be undefined in `$scope.sports = sports`

Comment: do I need to set up that code outside of ```$scope.doRefresh()``` for when the page loads for first time, and also I need to put it inside ```$scope.doRefresh()``` for when the user pull to refresh ?

Comment: you can call `$scope.doRefresh()` when your controller initializes, you don't need to declare it twice, the refresh just needs to wrap around the factory code.  also, note `$scope.$apply()` isn't necessary either.

Comment: how can I call it when the controller initializes ? sorry I am new to Angular

Comment: I just put all of my code inside ```$scope.doRefresh = function() {}``` but the content is not loading anymore.

Comment: it's a function, you call it the same way you are calling it from the button, `$scope.doRefresh()` while in the controller.

Comment: does this order make more sense to you?

Comment: of course, just I was worried about if I had to declare the same code twice.

Comment: @ClaiesI am getting an error once I try to call the function: ```TypeError: undefined is not a function``` ???

Comment: did you call it before or after it is declared in your controller? in other words, is `$scope.doRefresh()` at the top or the bottom of your controller?  it should be at the bottom.